# Does SQL Server have simplified cursor record fetching comparable to Oracle?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

For many years Oracle PL/SQL has featured an amazingly quick & simple method code for fetching from a cursor.  For a simple cursor like:

```
CURSOR emp_cur IS SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

columnnames are automatically fetched without explicitely naming them

```
FOR record IN emp_cur LOOP
 dbms_output.put_line('its ' || record.columnname );
END LOOP;
```

But all I've found in SQL Server requires explicit columns in the fetch statement, and other tedious boilerplate code like checking @@FETCH_STATUS, etc

Has SQL Server 2012 come up with something comparable to Oracle's simple technique?

Comment: You can simplify it even further if you want by putting the sql right in the FOR construct.

Comment: I know, and you're torturing me! Because Oracle is awesome like that and I wish I could code this easily in SQL SERVER, which is the mandate now.

Answer (score 0):

As at 2013-04-30, with the latest version of SQL Server being 2012, there is no such "syntactically equivalent" function to Oracle.  Whether it's good or bad is up for debate. The equivalent for what you have posited doesn't look that difficult, so I'm not sure what the gripe is.

```
declare @name varchar(10);
declare emp_cur cursor LOCAL STATIC FORWARD_ONLY for
    select name from employee;
open emp_cur;
fetch next from emp_cur into @name;
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
    PRINT 'its ' + @name;
    fetch next from emp_cur into @name;
end;
```